# CSS not working on my WordPress blog Homepage

Tags: css, wordpress

I am new on stack overflow and really would need some help to fix a problem on my WordPress blog ://

It looks like the css does not respond anymore yet I have no information about where the problem comes from. (I did not install any plugin recently)

Here are some screenshots to show you what it looks like ;)

I really hope you could help my solving this problem guys !! 
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your code and elobrate the requirement.

Comment: At least completing the site URL would do.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the problem is that there is another rule from a Theme or plugin that overcomes yours. You can try the following solutions.

1. **Set your custom rules as "!important"**
   In that way your rules will have higher priority and will overcome the defaults
2. **If the default rules are already set as "!important"**
   Then you will have to add the !important tag and make sure that they have higher priority from the others. For example to act on the element id instead of the class, or act after the defaults.
3. **Otherwise**
   If you can't set your rules with higher priority, just try to edit them. You can edit the theme's or your plugins css (or even better create a child theme).

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to clear your browser cache, sometimes, it might be the reason why your css doesn't work.
There is also a powerful plugin to add some css to your site, try installing it **Simple Custom Css**